# XAML Get data from binded elements

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have this XAML code:

```
<ListView Name="ListBoxWithNews" ItemsSource="{Binding News}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding imageURL}" Width="75" Height="75" />
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Title}" Width="200" />
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Body}" Width="200" />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The controls are binded using the MVVM pattern. The user can change the content of the two text boxes. Is there a possible way to get the updated text from these text boxes at some point when I need them?

Comment: Yes possible? but are not you binding those data from the properties you already defined?

Comment: Of course. Use `TwoWay` binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ViewModel should implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) and Use [`TwoWay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.mode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Binding as below

```
<ListView Name="ListBoxWithNews" ItemsSource="{Binding News,Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding imageURL,Mode=TwoWay}" Width="75" Height="75" />
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Title,Mode=TwoWay}" Width="200" />
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Body,Mode=TwoWay}" Width="200" />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: When I use TwoWay Binding the values will be changed in the array that I use to load the data right?

Comment: @user3523890 Yes exactly, You want to get the selected item from listview?

Comment: I want to get all the data from the text boxes including the changes that are made in them.

Comment: just one more question. How exactly should I implement the INotifyPropertyChanged to work?